# tWebService component - NullPointerException - createPropertyMapper

Tags: web-services, talend

I've a problem with the tWebService Talend component, impossible for me to find a solution

**My Job**

I have many WS to call in my job. I can call and get response with one simple WS (2 String param, and 2 String response)
But, for an other WS, more complex (String and Object param, and String and Object response), the tWebService failed. It looks the WS is not call, the problem seems to be Talend. But the MapperFactory failed to createPropertyMapper. My aim for moment is just to call the WS with static parameters and log the response with tLogRow component

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in component tWebService_9
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createPropertyMapper(MapperFactory.java:406)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createComplexTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:339)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:220)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createPropertyMapper(MapperFactory.java:423)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createComplexTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:339)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:220)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createPropertyMapper(MapperFactory.java:423)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createComplexTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:339)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:220)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createPropertyMapper(MapperFactory.java:423)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createComplexTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:339)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createTypeMapper(MapperFactory.java:220)
    at org.talend.webservice.mapper.MapperFactory.createMessageMapper(MapperFactory.java:208)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceInvokerHelper.createMessageMapper(ServiceInvokerHelper.java:165)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceInvokerHelper.getMessageMapper(ServiceInvokerHelper.java:157)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceInvokerHelper.invoke(ServiceInvokerHelper.java:184)
    at org.talend.webservice.helper.ServiceInvokerHelper.invoke(ServiceInvokerHelper.java:237)
    at ipad.test_0_1.test.tWebService_9Process(test.java:573)
    at ipad.test_0_1.test.runJobInTOS(test.java:921)
    at ipad.test_0_1.test.main(test.java:786)
```

If anybody can help me, I'll be so grateful !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems I can't just say "Hello" before my question, sorry, I don't know why, but "Hello ! " :)

Comment: Have you configured JDK? If you want to use webservices you should have JDK configured. If you don't do that you get all kind of weird errors.

Comment: Hello Balazs Gunics. Yes I configured it. I used 2 tWebServices before this, they worked perfectly, just this third didn't

Comment: I'm afraid you have to dig deeper. I'd go with debug mode and see if there's any side messages that helps.